# Reformulating a discrete model into a continuous model?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

> **Past Paper Question:**

Given a model of a ﬁsh population undergoing constant effort harvesting, where $N_i$ is the total population at time point $i$:

$$N_{i+1}=N_{i}+BN_{i}-DN_{i}^{2}-EN_{i},$$

where $BN_{i}$ are the number of births, $DN_{i}^{2}$ are the number of death, and $EN_{i}$ is the harvesting rate.

Reformulate the above model as a discrete model for constant yield ﬁshing, then take a small time limit to ﬁnd the equivalent continuous model.

> **My Attempt:**
>
> Not sure about the first part, but for the second part I think you make the substitution $N_{i+1}=N\left( t+\delta t\right)$ to get the form:
>   $$\dfrac {N\left( t+\delta t\right) -N\left( t\right) } {\delta t}=BN-DN^{2}-EN,$$
>   let $\delta t\rightarrow 0$ to give:
>   $$\dfrac {dN } {dt}=BN-DN^{2}-EN$$

**My Question:**

Is this the correct approach and what is the final answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is asked in the first part, we'll take a closer look at the given model.
$$N_{i+1} = N_i + BN_i - DN_i^2- EN_i$$
Because of the $EN_i$ term, the population being harvested is proportional (by a constant $E$) to the total amount of population at time $i$, e.g. $N_i$. This is known as *proportional harvesting* since the amount of harvest is proportional to the total number of population.

On to the question, *constant (rate) harvesting* means the population being harvested at each iteration is independent (or fixed) of the total population. This means that your new harvesting term should be just $E$. Thus your constant harvesting model looks like this:
$$N_{i+1} = N_i + BN_i - DN_i^2- E$$
**Note:** the meaning (and unit) of $E$ in both cases are different. In the first case, $E$ represents a unit-less proportion constant - which is sometimes expanded as the product of *catch-ability* and *effort*. On the other hand, in the second case, your $E$ is the fixed amount of population being harvested, thus it has unit of whatever species being considered.

For the second part, you are heading in the right direction. I will expand upon your attempt. Set $N_{i+1} = N(t+\delta t)$, this explicitly implies each time step is $\delta t$. To find the rate of change (or the differential equation) then subtracting $N_(t)$ from both sides:
$$N(t+\delta t) - N(t) = B N(t) - D N(t)^2 - E$$
Divide both sides by $\delta t$ to obtain:
$$\frac{N(t+\delta t) - N(t)}{\delta t} = \frac{B}{\delta t} N(t) - \frac{D}{\delta t} N(t)^2 - \frac{E}{\delta t}$$
It seems like if we take the limit as $\delta t \rightarrow 0$, the RHS will explode, but that is not the case. If we consider the way $B, D, E$ are defined, we'll realize that they can be represented by some fixed constant rate of changes $b, d, e$ multiplied with the time interval $\delta t$, e.g. $B = b \delta t$. Of course the meaning changes slightly, but significant between $B$ and $b$. The equation that we end up with using this changes of variable is:
$$\frac{N(t+\delta t) - N(t)}{\delta t} = b N(t) - d N(t)^2 - e$$
Taking the limit $\delta t \rightarrow 0$ with assumption on smoothness of $N$, then:
$$N'(t) = b N(t)\left[ 1 - d N(t)\right] - e$$

Comment: If your considering rates over a small period of time. By your logic above, if your now taking the constants as rates, would you not be left with: $$N(t+\delta t) - N(t) = \delta tB N(t) - \delta tD N(t)^2 - \delta tE$$ and so dividing by $\delta t$ and then taking the limit in this would avoid the blow up problem on the RHS, giving something similar to what I suggested.

Comment: @UniStuffz Yes, the approaches are similar. Just be careful with how the constants are defined.

Comment: The differential equation $$x'(t)=bx(t)(1-dx(t))-e$$ is obviously the continuous time model the authors of the exercise had in mind but it has little biological meaning as a continuous version of the discrete model $$N_{n+1}=N_n+bN_n(1-dN_n)-e$$ since its solutions are not such that $$x(t+s)=x(t)+b(s)x(t)(1-d(s)x(t))-e(s)$$ Actually it is well known that the discrete version of, say, $$x'(t)=rx(t)(1-ux(t))$$ is rather $$N_{n+1}=\frac{aN_n}{1+bN_n}$$ for some suitable parameters $(a,b)$.